# JSONP / Export to Excel

Tags: jquery, excel, jsonp

We're using JSONP (cross-site request) request with JQuery to retrieve data from our server; everything is fine.

But now we need to retrieve an Excel file; any idea / pointer on how to do that (we're using Firefox).

Thx.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this Excel file once you fetch it with jQuery? Wouldn't it be better to simply provide a link on the page so that the user can directly download the file and save it on his computer? Downloading files with AJAX isn't very practical.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity the generated file is not kept on the server; I'd the browser to propose to save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a server side handler on the remote domain which will serve the Excel file and append the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.xlsx` HTTP header so that the browser opens a Save As dialog. Now all that's left is provide the user with some link to download the file:

```
<a href="http://remotedomain.com/file">Download Excel file</a>
```

No javascript is required.

Comment: Thx. Got the idea; I've used a <form> and setup parameters accordingly at runtime.